Elliptic equation on differential forms
Let $\Sigma$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth closed manifold ($n\ge 3$) with a non-continuous metric $g\in W^{2,\frac{n}2}\cap L^{\infty}(\Sigma)$. Let $g'$ be a fixed smooth metric on $\Sigma$, there exists $\Lambda>1$ such that $\Lambda^{-1} g'_p(X,X)\le g_p(X,X)\le \Lambda g'_p(X,X)$ for a.e. $p\in \Sigma$ and any $X\in T_p(\Sigma)$. For a differential form $\alpha\in L^2(\Sigma,\Omega^k(\Sigma))$, assume we have $d^{*}\alpha=0$ and $d^*d\alpha=0$, where $d^*$ is the codifferential with respect to $g$. If $\alpha$ is a function, then it's a solution of the divergence-form elliptic PDE $\Delta_g \alpha=0$. A duality argument as in divergence-form regularity implies that $\alpha\in W^{1,p}$ for any $p<\infty$. And we can further prove that $\alpha\in W^{3,q}$ for any $q<\frac n2$.
If $\alpha$ is a $k$-form for $k\ge 1$, I wonder if we can get the same improvement of regularity. We have $\Delta_g \alpha=0$, which in local coordinates is a non-divergence-form elliptic system of equations. But it seems we can only get $\alpha\in W^{1,\frac{2n}{2+n}}$ and $\alpha\in W^{2,p}$ for any $p\ge 1$ satisfying $\frac 1p\ge \frac 12+\frac 2n$. Maybe this is really the best we can do, otherwise there should be other ways to use the condition $d^*\alpha=0$.

If $\alpha$ is a k-form with $k>0$, then the equation $d^{\ast}d\alpha=0$ is not elliptic. Instead, $(d^{\ast}d+dd^{\ast})\alpha=0$ is.

@G.Blaickner I know. What I'm asking is if one can make use of the condition $d^*\alpha=0$ in the equation $d^*d\alpha=0$ to make it a divergence-form elliptic system.

Since $\alpha$ is not a scalar function but, in local coordinates, is specified by a set of scalar functions, it is more comparable to a vecctor-valued function. In any case, have you tried to write the equations in local coordinates and checked whether they form a  divergence-free strongly elliptic system of PDEs? What did you get?

This question seems more suited to https://math.stackexchange.com/

@Overflowian I added more details. Indeed, it's less trivial than it appears to be.

@DeaneYang In the case $n=2$ and $g$ is conformal, I tried to insert $d^*\alpha=0$ in some sense to get a divergence-form system of equations, but it's weird: the system is easy to solve and improve regularity but the coefficients don't satisfy the criterion for strong ellipticity.

Could you provide the details of your calculation? What about doing the calculation in general using the formulas for $d^*\alpha$ and $d^*d\alpha$ in coordinates?

@DeaneYang I don't think my current computation is helpful...Maybe one could just consider the regularity problem as stated above (the equation holds in the distributional sense). If $\alpha$ is a function, then we can show that $\alpha\in W^{2,p}$ for any $p<n$. While if $\alpha$ is a $k$-form for $k\ge 1$, I'm not sure about the answer.

Is your manifold compact?

@Overflowian No. I'm looking for local regularity

I still suggest writing everything out in coordinates for the case where $\alpha$ is a $1$-form.

@DeaneYang Personally I suspect it's impossible to do so. No matter in what way we insert $d^*\alpha=0$ there will be non-divergence terms. If you haven't seen methods to rewrite the equation as a strongly elliptic divergence-form before, then I believe it's impossible to accomplish. I'm just not sure about the answer to the regularity problem

@TianLAN what's the problem with invoking elliptic regularity for the $\Delta$ operator?

@Overflowian Under the above restrictions on $g$, the benefit of homogeneous divergence-form equation is to improve solutions from $L^2$ to $W^{1,p}$ for any $p<\infty$ and $n\ge 3$. But for non-divergence form, at most we can get $W^{1,\frac{2n}{n+2}}$. Another issue is that since $d^d\alpha$ is not a well-defined distribution, we define $d^d\alpha=0$ by $dd\alpha=0$ instead, but $\Delta\alpha$ is still not a well-defined distribution. So a better way to deal with the condition $d^\alpha=0$ is to use $\alpha$ as the unknown and rewrite $dd^\alpha$ as a divergence-form w.r.t. $\alpha$.

@TianLAN my advice: I think that if you want to get some answers and upvotes you should explain extensively and clearly what are you hypothesis, what you want and what are the common approaches you considered and why they fail. You say that it's less trivial that it what appears to be, this shouldn't be part of the comments but should be explained in the question. That's not what the comment section is for.  Furthermore $d^$ is also the formal adjoint of $d$, so why isn't $d^ d\alpha $ already in divergence form? Making your question appreciated also by non-experts will give you moreupvotes.
